# How to calculate n(n+1)/2 for summation of two patterns?

Tags: arrays, math, sequence, combinatorics

Suppose I have an array with range till `n`, say 11, that is,

`U = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11`

Now, I have an array-A (a sub-array of U):

```
1 3 4 9
```

and a array-B(another sub-array of U with nothing in common with A):

```
2 5 6 10
```

Note that all these 3 sets are sorted.

I have to calculate `n(n+1)/2` for every `(a[i+1]-a[i]-1)` where `i` is the index of the array and `a` is the generalized array.

Also consider corner cases from both ends. They are to subtract 1 from first digit and then calculate `n(n+1)/2` and to subtract last digit from 11 and then calculate n(n+1)/2.

For eg. For set A : We get 
`(3-1-1)* + (4-3-1)* + (9-4-1)* + Corner Cases`
Here corner cases: `(1-0)* + (11-9)*`

x* means x(x+1)/2

Similarly for set B : We have `(5-2-1)* + (6-5-1)* + (10-6-1)* + (2-1)* + (11-10)*`

Now I have to calculate solution for (A U B) using set A and Set B in O(1) complexity. Is there a way to do this?

For O(N) complexity, I have just merge the two arrays and apply the above formula.

```
A U B : 1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10
```

Therefore solution = `(9-6-1)*+ (11-10)*`

Comment: No c++ code, no c++ answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use telescoping sum
([here's an exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2hpV.gif)).
I think about it because at each loop (each index of the array) you substract a number you add in the previous loop :

```
u[2] - u[1] - 1 + u[3] - u[2] - 1 + u[4] - u[3] - 1 + ... + u[n] - u[n-1]- 1
```

which gives you :

```
- u[1] - 1-...-1 + u[n]
= u[n] - n - u[1]
```

Moreover, A and B have nothing in common that's why:

```
n = lenght(A) + length (B)
```

Additionaly, since you order your numbers:

```
u[1] = min ( A[1] , B[1] )
u[n] = max ( A[length[A]] , B[length[B]] )
```

So we have it :

```
Solution = max ( A[length[A]] , B[length[B]] ) - lenght(A) - length (B) - min ( A[1] , B[1] )
```

I hope I helped you on this problem. (Sorry if I made some mistakes in english).